# How do I require fixtures in a pytest plugin?

Tags: python, plugins, pytest, fixtures

I followed [the pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/nonpython.html#yaml-plugin) to create this very simple attempt at a plugin:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def derp():
    return 42


def pytest_collect_file(parent, path):
    if path.ext == ".cool":
        return CoolFile.from_parent(parent, fspath=path)


class CoolFile(pytest.File):
    def collect(self):
        for i in ['cool', 'dude']:
            yield CoolItem.from_parent(self, name=i)


class CoolItem(pytest.Item):
    def __init__(self, name, parent):
        super().__init__(name, parent)

    def runtest(self, derp):
        assert False
```

The only problem here is that `runtest` does not actually use the fixture. Instead I get `FAILED foo.cool::cool - TypeError: runtest() missing 1 required positional argument: 'derp'`

So... what do I need to do here in order to make my test take the fixture? If I try and call the fixture then I get an error with documentation that says that I shouldn't be calling it directly instead I should use it as a parameter... but that doesn't work either. Adding `fixturenames` as a property of CoolItem doesn't work. I've searched pytest plugins for examples, to no avail, and the project linked from the docs is dead.

What *should* I be doing in order to get my `pytest.Item` to correctly use fixtures?

Comment: Fixtures are being fed to tests, not to the test runner protocol. It is the `runtest` that actually triggers fixture evaluation, so `derp` simply isn't initialized yet. What are you trying to achieve? Maybe you don't need a fixture?

Comment: I absolutely need a fixture. It could be accomplished some other way, but that would be reinventing the wheel. Specifically, I have yaml files that I need to turn into test cases. The example seemed very good but... Yeah.